# Are there any power supplies that can be used with a 2001-era computer?

Tags: power-supply

I have a computer from 2001 whose power supply probably needs to be replaced soon (the fan sometimes makes noises).  It is currently using a 10-year old FSP400-60PFN 400 watt PSU.  Power supplies from that era output the vast majority of their power on the 3.3V and 5V rails.  As you can see from the [FSP400-60PFN specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LDnA.jpg), it could output 235W combined on the 3.3V and 5V rails.

It seems modern power supplies output the vast majority of their power on the 12V rail.  One modern [430W PSU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBPcC.jpg) only outputs 120W combined on the 3.3V and 5V rails.  Even a [1600W PSU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnYnv.jpg) still only outputs 120W combined on the 3.3V and 5V rails.

I could try to get a used 2001-era power supply, but I'm not sure how reliable it would be since it may suffer from the "[capacitor plague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague)" problem of that era.

Are there any modern power supplies that output the vast majority of their power on the 3.3V and 5V rails?  It'd be nice if it had [Molex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akxGQ.jpg) connectors too.

Comment: Half wondering if reworking the caps and replacing the fan on an older PSU might be an option, Somewhat out of the scope of the site, but replacing electrolytics and fans isn't rocket science.

Comment: I agree with **Journeyman Geek**. Several of our production machines are old (DOS, WIn 3.11 and etc). It can be difficult finding replacement parts. So, I look at the electrolytics (capacitors) to see if they are expanded/bulging on the top. If they are, then they are failing/failed. Simply finding compatible replacements has fixed the issue.

Comment: Why can't you replace the computer with something low-end, but modern?  Money?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/ATX-Motherboard-Power-Converter-Cable/dp/B000E7JUVO  This is half your answer.

Comment: Look at this one:  http://www.evertek.com/viewpart.asp?auto=8380  Combined with my last entry.